# Angular4 CLI change favicon.ico to favicon.svg

Tags: angular-cli, favicon

I started to learn Angular 4 and try to remake one site using Angilar4 CLI.

Now I have a problem with new favicon that I drew in svg. I wrote this in index.html

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="any" href="favicon.svg">
```

And I deleted favicon.ico because it has been shown every time though I changed file.
Also I rewrote `.angular-cli.json` I changed

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
]
```

to

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.svg"
]
```

The favicon.svg is 16*16 px sized.

Comment: I've already seen that it added. But I can see it in Opera, Chrome shows some placeholder instead of favicon

Comment: Make sure to check the `angular.json` configuration to get the compilation to pull in the `.svg` over the default `.ico`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.
https://caniuse.com/#search=favicon
There we can see that chrome just doesn't support svg favicons

Comment: That is not the case anymore.